# how to correctly replace bytes with memset?

Tags: c, random

I need to patch first 23 bytes of 32 bytes randomly generated by the `rand256` function but it seems `memset` isn't correctly patching.

```
0000000000000000000000C90F4094919B9FAE4616149C0FDC61E7C1F318E234
```

as you can see, `memset` added only 23 zeroes whereas I am expecting 46 zeroes.
Now I am wondering if there is something like `zfill` that can correctly fill 23 bytes with zeros.

```
union uint256_s
{
    uint8_t i8[32];
    uint16_t i16[16];
    uint32_t i32[8];
    uint64_t i64[4];
};
typedef union uint256_s uint256_t;
static uint256_t rand256(struct seed *seed)
{
    seed->counter++;
    return sha256(seed, sizeof(struct seed));
}

static uint256_t rand256_and_mask(struct seed *seed)
{
    uint256_t r = rand256(seed);
    memset(&r, 0x000, 23);
    return r;
}

struct seed {
    uint256_t seed;
    uint128_t counter;
};

static inline uint256_t sha256(const void *data, size_t len)
{
    secp256k1_sha256_t cxt;
    secp256k1_sha256_initialize(&cxt);
    secp256k1_sha256_write(&cxt, (uint8_t *)data, (int)len);
    uint256_t res;
    secp256k1_sha256_finalize(&cxt, (uint8_t *)&res);
    return res;
}
static void *init_worker(void *arg)
{
    struct seed *seed = make_seed();
    size_t i = (size_t)arg;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < OFFSET_MAX_ROW; j++)
    {
        int overflow = 0;
        do
        {
            uint256_t x = rand256_and_mask(seed);
            secp256k1_scalar_set_b32(&priv_offsets[j][i], x.i8 + 12, &overflow);
        }
        while (overflow);
        secp256k1_gej_t tmp;
        secp256k1_ecmult_gen(&cxt->ecmult_gen_ctx, &tmp, &priv_offsets[j][i]);
        secp256k1_ge_set_gej(&offsets[j][i], &tmp);
    }
    free(seed);
    putchar('.');
    fflush(stdout);

    return NULL;
}
```

how can I correctly patch first 23 bytes?

Comment: `as you can see, memset added only 23 zeroes` How are you checking that, exactly?

Comment: The 64-character hex value, which represents the 32 bytes of a 256-bit value, has its most significant bits clear. From that, your system must be big-endian? Is that the case?

Comment: The function `rand256_and_mask()` which calls `memset()` isn't itself used in the code shown.

Comment: nor is the code that prints the 'bad' value. Complete testable code please

Comment: `memset(&r, 0x000, 23);` Have you tried to pass the second parameter with 0 (zero)? Its just an unsigned char conversion of the value anyway. And the third parameter is set to 23 as you stated in the first sentence. Why do you expect 46 zeros?

Comment: @ptr2n0 perhaps because 23 bytes should show as 46 characters in hexadecimal text. The whole thing is unclear, though.

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe I'm misinterpreting this, but if a char array is given you just patch the wanted bytes with the char you choose. In that case it is plain 0. If you need to do 23 Bytes you write `memset(&r, '0', 23);` and if you need 46 Bytes aka 46 zeros you write to the third parameter 46.
See: [link](https://onlinegdb.com/vkzgrWWTv)

Comment: @ptr2n0: no, `r` is a `uint256_t`, which is a 256 bit integer occupying 32 bytes. Yet the OP does not provide the code that outputs the textual representation, which might be incorrect.

Comment: What exactly is `uint256_t` type?

Comment: @BsMthethwa:"  as you can see, memset added only 23 zeroes" --> "0000000000000000000000C90F4094919B9FAE4616149C0FDC61E7C1F318E234" has 22 leading zeros in its 64 digit length.  Where is the 23 coming from? a mis-count?

Comment: @BsMthethwa, `rand256_and_mask()` is never called.  No evidence that `memset(&r, 0x000, 23);` ever called.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: the program outputs uint256 in hexadecimal, so i think since i replaced the first 23 bytes with 0s the value of r is no longer 32bytes, its just a theory

Comment: @dimich its union

Comment: @BsMthethwa Thanks, i see the post is updated. How do you monitor `x` value? Try `for (int i=0; i<32; ++i) printf(" %02X", x.i8[i]); printf("\n");`  right after `uint256_t x = rand256_and_mask(seed);`

Comment: @dimich you are right, x is correctly patched, after putting the above code i get `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 02 3B 57 B5 92 94 21 80`